# Best way to confine given string to white list

Tags: python, django

I have a urlconf setup to catch /account/invoices/*/, and with it I want to catch a few optional qualifiers. In this case: unpaid, paid, disregarded. I'm not outputting this so I think accepting input in this fashion should be fine, but still I need to white list and translate these options into what the API expects. Is there a better way to do this (where the variable 'paid' comes in as a view argument)?

```
filter['unpaid'] = 0
filter['paid'] = 1
filter['disregarded'] = 2

if paid is in filter:
    paid = filter[paid]
```

Comment: Not sure which part of this you'd like to improve, and not sure what you consider "better".  The if statement could be substituted by `paid = filter.get(paid, paid)`, assuming `filter` is a dictionary.

Comment: filter.get looks good. I'm new to python so I'm always trying to get feedback on my code. There are a lot of syntactic niceties that don't exist in PHP that I want to leverage.

Comment: and also, naming something "filter" is not a good idea. it can conflict with builtin filter function.

Comment: duly noted. should know better

Comment: `is in` is invalid syntax; you just want `if paid in filter:`

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
if paid in ['unpaid', 'paid', 'disregarded']
```

Your solution and DataGreed's are more verbose and require you to make up values for your dict/object elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution is good. But i just like dict.get a little more:

```
enum = {
        'unpaid'      : 0,
        'paid'        : 1,
        'disregarded' : 2,
        }


def view(request, option):

    value = enum.get(option, None)
```